# Files not detected from from the `resources` directory

Tags: java

I am trying to import a file from `resources` in my project. I specified the `SOLVER_CONFIG` to take in `solver.xml` from the root of `resources`.

```
package in.co.technovia.sudoku;

import java.util.ArrayList;
....
public class App{
    private static final String SOLVER_CONFIG = "/solver.xml";
    public static void main(String[] args){
    SudokuGenerator sg = new SudokuGenerator();
    ....
    }

    private static Solver createSolver(){

    XmlSolverConfigurer configurer = new XmlSolverConfigurer();
        configurer.configure(SOLVER_CONFIG);
        return configurer.buildSolver();
    }
}
```

It's supposed to take `solver.xml` from the root of `resources`. It works in [this case](https://github.com/diega/drools-planner-poc/blob/master/src/main/java/ar/com/plugtree/abfm/poc/DroolsPlannerPoCApp.java), but the capricious Java gods decreed otherwise for my project:

```
jesvin@Jesvin-Technovia:~/dev/drools/sudoku$ java in.co.technovia.sudoku.AppException in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The solver configuration (/solver.xml) does not exist.
    at org.drools.planner.config.XmlSolverConfigurer.configure(XmlSolverConfigurer.java:79)
    at in.co.technovia.sudoku.App.createSolver(App.java:67)
    at in.co.technovia.sudoku.App.main(App.java:43)
```

**Question:** Why isnt Java detecting the files from `resources`?

---

I included the contents of the `src/main/java/in/co/technovia/sudoku/` application and  the `src/main/resources/` directory and the current classpath.

```
jesvin@Jesvin-Technovia:~/dev/drools/sudoku$ ls src/main/resources/
score.drl  score.drl~  solver.xml  solver.xml~

jesvin@Jesvin-Technovia:~/dev/drools/sudoku$ ls src/main/java/in/co/technovia/sudoku/
App.class  App.java~  helloworld.class  helloworld.java~
App.java   domain     helloworld.java   solution

jesvin@Jesvin-Technovia:~/dev/drools/sudoku$ export | grep CLASSPATHdeclare -x   
CLASSPATH=".:/home/jesvin/dev/drools/sudoku/binaries/*:/home/jesvin/dev/drools/sudoku/src/main/java"
```

---

**Solution:** As **khmarbaise** says in his answers, the directory is meant for a maven build. So to include the directory, see ' https://stackoverflow.com/a/9045680/604511 '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seemed to mistaken the folder src/main/resources with it's intention in a Maven build. The folder src/main/resources is copied during the build into target/classes folder which represents the resources which you can use in your java application by using:

```
this.getResourceAsStream("/solver.xml")...
```

which gives you back a InputStream instead of a File object. The following can be used to get a file out of it, but this approach doesn't work with JARs in your classpath, only with files and directories.

```
URL dir_url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(dir_path);
// Turn the resource into a File object
File dir = new File(dir_url.toURI());
```

Comment: "it's intention in a Maven build", But [this project](https://github.com/diega/drools-planner-poc/tree/master/src/main) I am modeling it on doesnt seem to be a Maven build.

Comment: Yes, the resource is already used [like you described](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/org.drools.solver/drools-solver-core/5.0.0.M5/org/drools/solver/config /XmlSolverConfigurer.java#XmlSolverConfigurer.configure%28java.lang.String%29) But how to get it to point it to the right place?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
    private static final String SOLVER_CONFIG = "resources/solver.xml";
```

The fact that you add a directory to your classpath, does not mean that Java will use that directory to find external files. It only means that it will use that directory to find classes inside of it.

A `solver.xml` file is not a class file. You are probably accessing `solver.xml` through file system related classes such as:

```
File f = new File("solver.xml");
```

So that file needs to be found in the file system. If you use `"/solver.xml"` you are telling java to open a file named `solver.xml` which lies in root `/` directory.

Comment: Try using an abosulte path for your solver file. Such as `/tmp/solver.xml`. And try reflecting that in `SOLVER_CONFIG` variable.

Comment: Pablo I would just add info about loading resource via `Class.getResourceAsStream(...)`. That and your answer should be plenty to resolve the problem.