# How to have the equivalent of main/resources in a non-Maven project?

Tags: java

I was trying to model my project based on [this project](https://github.com/diega/drools-planner-poc) at Github.

```
public class DroolsPlannerPoCApp {
....
private static final String   SOLVER_CONFIG    = "/ServiceDeliverySolverConfig.xml";
....
private Solver createSolver() {
        XmlSolverConfigurer configurer = new XmlSolverConfigurer();
        configurer.configure( SOLVER_CONFIG );
        return configurer.buildSolver();
    }
```

The file mentioned in `SOLVER_CONFIG` lies in the `resources` directory ([see here](https://github.com/diega/drools-planner-poc/tree/master/src/main/resources)).

---

I tried to do the **same thing**.

```
package in.co.technovia.sudoku;

import java.util.ArrayList;
....
public class App{
    private static final String SOLVER_CONFIG = "/solver.xml";
    public static void main(String[] args){
    SudokuGenerator sg = new SudokuGenerator();
    ....
    }

    private static Solver createSolver(){

    XmlSolverConfigurer configurer = new XmlSolverConfigurer();
        configurer.configure(SOLVER_CONFIG);
        return configurer.buildSolver();
    }
}
```

And there was fail.

```
jesvin@Jesvin-Technovia:~/dev/drools/sudoku$ java in.co.technovia.sudoku.AppException in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The solver configuration (/solver.xml) does not exist.
    at org.drools.planner.config.XmlSolverConfigurer.configure(XmlSolverConfigurer.java:79)
    at in.co.technovia.sudoku.App.createSolver(App.java:67)
    at in.co.technovia.sudoku.App.main(App.java:43)
```

I understand that `main/resources` mean something for **Maven builds**. But I am building my project manually.

**Question:** How do I implement the same thing (from resources) in my own project? Where must I place the file and what must I specify in the SOLVER_CONFIG?

---

The [function itself](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/org.drools.solver/drools-solver-core/5.0.0.M5/org/drools/solver/config/XmlSolverConfigurer.java#52) is implemented as:

```
public XmlSolverConfigurer configure(String resource) {
    return configure(getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the resources on the classpath, for example, in the source directory.

All Maven does is merge the `src/main/resources` package/directory tree into the target classpath, maintaining the same package/folder layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you build manually you need to copy the resources manually into the classpath, i.e. copy the XML file in the root path of your generated classes directory.